SwiftShield Obfuscation Fails to Exclude Pods Files Properly
I am using SwiftShield to obfuscate my project, but despite using exclusion flags (--ignore-names, --ignore-targets), it continues to process certain files from the Pods directory, causing errors. Specifically, files like ResponseSerialization.swift and Concurrency.swift from Alamofire are being processed, even though they are intended to be excluded.
Run SwiftShield with Exclusion Flags:

sudo swiftshield obfuscate 
--project-file "fySDK.xcworkspace" 
--scheme "fySDK" 
--ignore-names "fySDK/Pods/*" 
--verbose

error

error response (Request Failed): '/Volumes/Project/fySDK/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Features/ResponseSerialization.swift' is not part of the input files


error response (Request Failed): '/Volumes/Project/fySDK/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Features/Concurrency.swift' is not part of the input files

Please assist with resolving the issue where SwiftShield does not properly exclude Pods files from obfuscation. Any guidance or fixes would be greatly appreciated.
